# When does conjugating one generator in $F_2$ give an automorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $F_2$ be the free group on generators $x,y$.

For $w\in F_2$, consider homomorphisms $\alpha_w : F_2\rightarrow F_2$ sending

$$\alpha_w : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
x & \mapsto & x \\
y & \mapsto & wyw^{-1}
\end{array}\right.$$

For which $w$ is $\alpha_w$ an automorphism? Is there a name for the set of $\alpha_w$'s which are automorphisms?

Comment: I would guess if and only if $w=x^iy^j$, but I don't have time to think about it right now. There is an algorithm, the *Whitehead Algorithm* for determining whether a set of $n$ elements freely generates $F_n$, and I expect you could use this to resolve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a theorem of Lyndon Schupp in combinatorial group theory, we know that :

$$Out(\mathbb{F}_2)\text{ is isomorphic to } Aut(\mathbb{F}_2^{Ab}) $$

Furthermore $\mathbb{F}_2^{Ab}=\mathbb{Z}^2$ hence :

$$Aut(\mathbb{F}_2^{Ab})=GL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $$

Now the correspondance can be made explicit, if $\psi\in Aut(\mathbb{F}_2)$ then write the image of the two generators (say $a$ and $b$) in terms of maybe non reduced words into those generators :

$$\psi(a)=a^{k_1}b^{l_1}...a^{k_s}b^{l_s} \text{ and }\psi(b)=a^{k_1'}b^{l_1'}...a^{k_{s'}'}b^{l_{s'}'} $$

I claim now that through the isomorphism, $[\psi]$ will be sent to the matrix :

$$\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^sk_i&\sum_{i=1}^{s'}k_i'\\\sum_{i=1}^sl_i&\sum_{i=1}^{s'}l_i'\end{pmatrix} $$

Now apply this to $\alpha_w$, that is if $\alpha_w$ is an automorphism then its outer-class is represented by $I_2$ (the identity matrix). So that if $\alpha_w$ is an automorphism then it is necessarily inner.

Hence there should be a word $v$ such that $vxv^{-1}=\alpha_w(x)=x$ and $vyv^{-1}=\alpha_w(y)=wyw^{-1}$ Hence we should have :

$$v\in Z_{\mathbb{F}_2}(x)\text{ and } w^{-1}v\in Z_{\mathbb{F}_2}(y)$$

Since $Z_{\mathbb{F}_2}(x)=<x>$ and  $Z_{\mathbb{F}_2}(y)=<y>$ it follows that we should have :

$$v=x^k\text{ and } w=x^ky^l $$

Hence we have shown that for any $\alpha_w$ group automorphism, $w=x^ky^l$ and then $\alpha_w$ is the conjugation by $x^k$. Reciprocally every conjugation by $x^k$ is of this form and we can conclude that the automorphism you are highlighting are just inner automorphism by $x^k$.

Comment: of course! Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: What if I replaced $F_2$ with its profinite completion and asked the same question? What can be said in that case?